# Euler factors of L-function at bad primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, l-functions

This is of course a very-well known problem, but still let me ask the questions my way. Let $L(s)$ be a "motivic" $L$-function, whatever that means: in particular, it has an Euler product (including at "bad" primes), and a (possibly conjectural) functional equation of standard type with an arithmetic conductor $N$ occurring as $N^{s/2}$ in the factor at infinity. Let $p$ be a prime, denote by $L_p(s)$ the denominator of the Euler factor at $p$, by $d_p$ the degree of $L_p(s)$ in $p^{-s}$, and by $v_p(N)$ the valuation of $N$ at $p$. Finally let $d$ be the degree of the $L$-function, equal both to the number of $\Gamma_{\mathbb R}(s)$ factors and to the generic degree in $p^{-s}$ of $L_p(s)$.

I define a prime to be good if it does not divide $N$ (note that if $L$ comes from a variety with bad reduction at $p$, it may still be a good prime in this sense). For the following statements, please tell me if they are true, or only sometimes true, sometimes false (and in that case possibly some extra info):

1) If $p$ is good then $d_p=d$.

2) If $d_p=d$ then $p$ is good.

3) $v_p\ge d-d_p$

4) I know that one can have $v_p>d-d_p$, but can one give a reasonably simple criterion for equality ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1) True.

2) True.

3) True.

4) They are equal in the case of "tame ramification", e.g. if the degree of $K(\mu_p)$ over $K$, $K$ the coefficient field of the motive, is greater than $d$.

One just has to recall that for $V$ the $\ell$-adic Galois representation associated to the motive, $\dim V$ is the degree of the $L$-function, the local $L$-factor is the characteristic polynomial of $\operatorname{Frob}_p$ on the invariants of the inertia group at $p$, and a prime is good if and only if the inertia group acts nontrivially. Furthermore $v_p$ is the Artin conductor which consists of the codimension of the inertia invariant subspace (i.e. $d-d_p$) plus the Swan conductor.

The Swan conductor vanishes if and only if the wild inertia group acts trivially. The last claim depends on something that I think is still conjectural, depending on the theory of motives, which is that the characteristic polynomials of elements of the Weil group are defined over $K$. From this, it follows immediately, as these characteristic polynomials have degree $d$, and for elements of teh wild inertia group, roots $p$-power roots of unity.

Comment: Nice answer. It is worthwhile to add that 1), 2), 3) are also true for automorphic $L$-functions (in which case "good" is called "unramified"). Due to the inductive nature of local admissible representations, it suffices to show this when the underlying local representation of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ is supercuspidal. Then, distinguishing between $n=1$ and $n\geq 2$, the statement follows from known facts. For example, in the latter case, the local conductor is at least $p^n$, while the local $L$-function is $1$.

Comment: @GHfromMO I think an appropriate version of 4 is fine in the automorphic context too...

Comment: Sure, but I don't know the relevant structure theory. I think (6.1.2) in the 1998 JAMS paper of Bushnell-Henniart-Kutzko is relevant, but I have not studied the details.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these very informative answers and comments!

Comment: @WillSavin: Something I don't understand concerning 4: if $L$ is the $L$-function of an elliptic curve over Q with conductor divisible by $27$, we have $v_p\ge3$ but $d-d_p\le2$ and $Q(\mu_p)\ne Q$. What gives?

Comment: @HenriCohen $d=2$ and the degree of $\mathbb Q(\mu_p)$ over $\mathbb Q$ is $2$, thus isn't greater than $d_p$.

Comment: Sorry,. misread your answer. Thanks.